# Copy and register DLL into system 32 using MSI

Tags: windows-installer, dllregistration

I built an application using VS2015 Enterprise. My application had several library projects.I created an MSI for the same application.I am facing an issue that I want to copy some DLL from application to system 32 folder and register them using regsvr32 command using same MSI.I don't want to do this manually or separately after installing the MSI.Is there any way or how to do this by using custom action in MSI?
Note:We have all the required DLL and project output of all library project in MSI installation directory.Thus How to copy DLL from msi installation directory to system 32 and later how  register them using MSI?
Help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a VS 2015 installer project or some other tool to create the MSI file? And are you building a 32-bit MSI or a 64-bit one?

Comment: I am using VS 2015 installer project to create 64 bit MSI.Also we want to copy 64 bit DLL so I think it should be copied into system32 and later we need to register DLL using regsvr32.exe "DllName.dll" /s.